# Como escrever um schema do tipo List no Python Eve?

Tags: python

Estou escrevendo um schema e preciso entender como fazer um `list` utilizando o [Python Eve](http://python-eve.org/) e [Cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#schema-list). Atualmente escrevo como a documentação me ensina:

`'datasources': {'type': 'list', 'schema':{'type':'string'}}`

Mas quando tento enviar um POST com uma lista para esse parâmetro continuo recebendo

`"datasources": "must be of list type"`.

Ja tentei enviando das seguintes maneiras:

`'teste1,teste2'`,
`[teste1,teste2]`,
`['teste1','teste2'],`
`'[teste1,teste2]'`.  Mas nenhuma dessas são aceitas. Nem mesmo utilizando o exemplo dado no link do Cerberus consigo mandar uma lista. Alguma ideia do porquê?

Comment: O jeito correto é: ['valor1', 'valor2']. O que você deve se atentar é se realmente o que você tá tentando validar é realmente uma lista, ou uma string que representa uma lista.

Se você está recebendo um valor através de POST, ele provavelmente não vai ser uma lista, e sim um string. Nesse caso você vai ter que converter pra lista.

Pra confirmar minha hipótese, pegue a "lista"  que você está recebendo via POST, e teste pelo seguinte comando: `print(type(lista))`. O valor correto dessa saída para funcionar corretamente deve ser `<type 'list'>`